# Macbook Pro 2013 freezing after MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My Macbook Pro late 2013 is freezing except for the mouse still moves but is inoperable - Ive never had this issue before installing High Sierra - I can be watching YouTube and I can expect my mac to lockup after 15/20mins .. weird thing is I can still hear the audio - but the vision and all apps are frozen - I have done all that's been suggested such as resetting the NVRAM and SMC many times .. also I have ran  Disk Utility plus CleanMyMac app multiple times - I have searched and found similar issue is happening with a lot of MacBook users running High Sierra.

Has anyone got any further information or tips I can try to resolve this?

much appreciated
- Mark